# IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0 despite identical shape

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sequentialfeatureselector

I want to retrieve the features selected by forward sequential selection. Both the `feature_names.shape` and `sfs_forward.get_support().shape` are `(1185,)` but my code raised `IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 6 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1185`.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector

X = df.iloc[:,:-1]
y = df.T.loc["subtype",:]

scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X)
X_scaled = scaler.transform(X)
X_scaled = X_scaled[~np.isnan(X_scaled).all(axis=1)]

feature_names = np.array(X.columns)

tic_fwd = time()
sfs_forward = SequentialFeatureSelector(
    ridge, n_features_to_select=2, direction="forward"
).fit(X_scaled, y_transformed)
toc_fwd = time()


print(
    "Features selected by forward sequential selection: "
    f"{feature_names[sfs_forward.get_support()]}"
)
print(f"Done in {toc_fwd - tic_fwd:.3f}s")
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [27], in <cell line: 7>()
      2 sfs_forward = SequentialFeatureSelector(
      3     ridge, n_features_to_select=2, direction="forward"
      4 ).fit(X_scaled, y_transformed)
      5 toc_fwd = time()
      7 print(
      8     "Features selected by forward sequential selection: "
----> 9     f"{feature_names[sfs_forward.get_support()]}"
     10 )
     11 print(f"Done in {toc_fwd - tic_fwd:.3f}s")

IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 6 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1185
```

feature_names.shape

```
(1185,)
```

sfs_forward.get_support().shape

```
(1185,)
```

Data:

`df.iloc[0:20,0:20]`

```
pd.DataFrame({'AAAS': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A': 3.33370417925201,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A': 3.34925376425734,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A': 3.30349695880794,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A': 3.38096309720271,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A': 3.36824732623076,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A': 3.38620967759704,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A': 3.31614461640547,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A': 3.24948718071353,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A': 3.31237602614007,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A': 3.25339435578418,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A': 3.2546210341103,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A': 3.30663948227448,
  'TCGA.4A.A93W.01A': 3.32680623499096,
  'TCGA.4A.A93X.01A': 3.36733999973516,
  'TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A': 3.2308076918096,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A': 3.34943784290226,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A': 3.37136358330499,
  'TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A': 3.25515446854463,
  'TCGA.A4.7288.01A': 3.24471275993211,
  'TCGA.A4.7583.01A': 3.28988441955171},
 'AARSD1': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A': 3.26191613710211,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A': 3.32510595062856,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A': 3.33666480834738,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A': 3.38548662709543,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A': 3.31393112898833,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A': 3.3844029363488,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A': 3.27589892329404,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A': 3.3066208734883,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A': 3.32080678472723,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A': 3.20905567146907,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A': 3.31482810573583,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A': 3.52527394202135,
  'TCGA.4A.A93W.01A': 3.35791864748117,
  'TCGA.4A.A93X.01A': 3.37992172225646,
  'TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A': 3.18332212236444,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A': 3.25702110554208,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A': 3.40073840803568,
  'TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A': 3.37357419609698,
  'TCGA.A4.7288.01A': 3.20843689886653,
  'TCGA.A4.7583.01A': 3.17575870968208},
 'AASS': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A': 2.98072012253114,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A': 3.05313491041203,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A': 3.08982082695446,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A': 3.00519898142942,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A': 3.28265423939019,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A': 3.29249451483352,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A': 3.18509958679916,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A': 3.2315468449309,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A': 3.24916735666473,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A': 3.1258891511562,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A': 3.04486585947894,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A': 3.23762408943738,
  'TCGA.4A.A93W.01A': 3.21564519349256,
  'TCGA.4A.A93X.01A': 3.14471380201247,
  'TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A': 2.86957141026716,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A': 3.31900309673507,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A': 3.47228157297442,
  'TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A': 3.25224311787039,
  'TCGA.A4.7288.01A': 3.37181034609328,
  'TCGA.A4.7583.01A': 2.97624235592413},
 'ABHD11': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A': 3.45442444300391,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A': 3.63034209087263,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A': 3.70172491168742,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A': 3.57422385519763,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A': 3.58687437256901,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A': 3.71221697435946,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A': 3.37728221732592,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A': 3.46371103636162,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A': 3.28426031477005,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A': 3.30783066520687,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A': 3.29006167425864,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A': 3.73402375932904,
  'TCGA.4A.A93W.01A': 3.59371860683494,
  'TCGA.4A.A93X.01A': 3.45704018264931,
  'TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A': 3.08886551011693,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A': 3.41635876686342,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A': 3.59970761273578,
  'TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A': 3.53254635077263,
  'TCGA.A4.7288.01A': 3.41278712830029,
  'TCGA.A4.7583.01A': 3.42935144956267},
 'ABHD14A': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A': 3.23147506581216,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A': 3.24014574406411,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A': 3.27383206099273,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A': 3.43484025303272,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A': 3.33930301693651,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A': 3.27533712036305,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A': 3.21653166674538,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A': 3.21643407871312,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A': 3.00036464916413,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A': 3.11196153347818,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A': 3.16294707051804,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A': 3.39978790688454,
  'TCGA.4A.A93W.01A': 3.31204401612052,
  'TCGA.4A.A93X.01A': 3.28175308875134,
  'TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A': 3.12689338571482,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A': 3.2136834012932,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A': 3.41998236517117,
  'TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A': 3.28578845771729,
  'TCGA.A4.7288.01A': 3.11798185586533,
  'TCGA.A4.7583.01A': 3.12518643871903},
 'ACADVL': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A': 3.78280804969722,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A': 3.83518906941955,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A': 3.76545652291492,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A': 3.85661653659097,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A': 3.83510247236515,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A': 3.84184572618095,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A': 3.69669745512717,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A': 3.85849814535531,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A': 3.53745376464629,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A': 3.70779377411552,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A': 3.73824585940869,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A': 3.82111655432968,
  'TCGA.4A.A93W.01A': 3.74776019274385,
  'TCGA.4A.A93X.01A': 3.73967865238708,
  'TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A': 3.6096519713675,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A': 3.78368869116589,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A': 3.85963550251591,
  'TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A': 3.84480066470514,
  'TCGA.A4.7288.01A': 3.77059403979435,
  'TCGA.A4.7583.01A': 3.72736487982992},
 'ACAP3': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A': 3.32954742137758,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A': 3.41541368621735,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A': 3.36566885760338,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A': 3.33905458589913,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A': 3.38268360006463,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A': 3.34139213854099,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A': 3.17685206178369,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A': 3.32621206175931,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A': 3.24132329884539,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A': 3.30200263604801,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A': 3.20113494357782,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A': 3.35158056517227,
  'TCGA.4A.A93W.01A': 3.33261563288546,
  'TCGA.4A.A93X.01A': 3.1966941080367,
  'TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A': 3.21085184816322,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A': 3.26776798309195,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A': 3.42466062536747,
  'TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A': 3.3650830203683,
  'TCGA.A4.7288.01A': 3.29758758210549,
  'TCGA.A4.7583.01A': 3.26616973598172},
 'ACBD4': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A': 3.21956455097052,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A': 3.32785669741002,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A': 3.2418493958081,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A': 3.30161312786773,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A': 3.32693496452319,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A': 3.28751140605353,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A': 3.20938204942816,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A': 3.36919924778803,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A': 3.40181000812383,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A': 3.13353744600034,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A': 3.1145673700832,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A': 3.34807071937758,
  'TCGA.4A.A93W.01A': 3.32255564941828,
  'TCGA.4A.A93X.01A': 3.30076059153253,
  'TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A': 3.03931699339692,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A': 3.2826557489973,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A': 3.37714647778826,
  'TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A': 3.28917834179844,
  'TCGA.A4.7288.01A': 3.28256155124117,
  'TCGA.A4.7583.01A': 3.21775779894534},
 'ACCS': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A': 3.08010926641183,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A': 3.09519418745071,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A': 2.95156697395897,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A': 3.14871798236364,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A': 3.03283334713975,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A': 3.15683664831187,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A': 3.18228546185869,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A': 3.04138390728031,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A': 3.13518600021314,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A': 3.22051322331053,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A': 3.08699890758702,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A': 3.06401024012122,
  'TCGA.4A.A93W.01A': 3.10037474872627,
  'TCGA.4A.A93X.01A': 2.95016687098414,
  'TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A': 2.95666547736711,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A': 3.13587768187161,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A': 3.25054412692135,
  'TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A': 3.11025888222529,
  'TCGA.A4.7288.01A': 3.11711368678687,
  'TCGA.A4.7583.01A': 3.2006222452079},
 'ACD': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A': 3.19213021131488,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A': 3.20320857814628,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A': 3.27909112568773,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A': 3.26095012781228,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A': 3.28871557525255,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A': 3.29586744440765,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A': 3.08874481336118,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A': 2.97338991241771,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A': 3.1370575129655,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A': 3.20822079478193,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A': 3.06189501848873,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A': 3.3430789326483,
  'TCGA.4A.A93W.01A': 3.23304663525791,
  'TCGA.4A.A93X.01A': 3.18568664760788,
  'TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A': 3.13147026186541,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A': 3.14939442580704,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A': 3.32606932827815,
  'TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A': 3.22704497470063,
  'TCGA.A4.7288.01A': 3.18050836413849,
  'TCGA.A4.7583.01A': 3.24419966423062},
 'ACIN1': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A': 3.52466908578752,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A': 3.49823196362438,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A': 3.5384640251653,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A': 3.52901663287839,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A': 3.54970618687924,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A': 3.51153640599344,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A': 3.51818510120471,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A': 3.45115379307268,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A': 3.4771783753439,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A': 3.52002142731939,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A': 3.47275579005186,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A': 3.47428336826483,
  'TCGA.4A.A93W.01A': 3.56033538819405,
  'TCGA.4A.A93X.01A': 3.50976760204467,
  'TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A': 3.49973868495901,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A': 3.53737918710136,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A': 3.60706135661057,
  'TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A': 3.4657077451802,
  'TCGA.A4.7288.01A': 3.45293350052245,
  'TCGA.A4.7583.01A': 3.40895204511546},
 'ACOT8': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A': 3.27349420687854,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A': 3.27165000646019,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A': 3.12574135882714,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A': 3.24545320135566,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A': 3.13323469818501,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A': 3.2594849047236,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A': 3.18167802281569,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A': 3.10346157568027,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A': 3.09334519884808,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A': 3.04072639178277,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A': 3.16322186930956,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A': 3.28412005110336,
  'TCGA.4A.A93W.01A': 3.2501750422424,
  'TCGA.4A.A93X.01A': 3.36050511144836,
  'TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A': 3.1401191871727,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A': 3.17911015544583,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A': 3.28520144124094,
  'TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A': 3.14282311422587,
  'TCGA.A4.7288.01A': 3.01050928041973,
  'TCGA.A4.7583.01A': 3.12532635195293},
 'ACSL3': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A': 3.31134536026302,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A': 3.35712910880047,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A': 3.30632285397452,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A': 3.27441467093657,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A': 3.25938746147772,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A': 3.20057626573749,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A': 3.34746436020073,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A': 3.28640782993935,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A': 3.31470578824798,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A': 3.36066736921985,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A': 3.34372487268323,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A': 3.22159484589212,
  'TCGA.4A.A93W.01A': 3.2573328000576,
  'TCGA.4A.A93X.01A': 3.17519813374988,
  'TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A': 3.35098384485933,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A': 3.18530672589519,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A': 3.15541603600036,
  'TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A': 3.30879900337964,
  'TCGA.A4.7288.01A': 3.28347444017644,
  'TCGA.A4.7583.01A': 3.4451627404573},
 'ACTR2': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A': 3.61231510694424,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A': 3.52383957062255,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A': 3.53563667297091,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A': 3.52479258838548,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A': 3.47510625125214,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A': 3.5161992464569,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A': 3.61256790636486,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A': 3.55425150651787,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A': 3.62664331413751,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A': 3.64993947223951,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A': 3.54973675800032,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A': 3.38380496795406,
  'TCGA.4A.A93W.01A': 3.53646676734563,
  'TCGA.4A.A93X.01A': 3.55261699745398,
  'TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A': 3.65133654532084,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A': 3.54739323593656,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A': 3.43657127029103,
  'TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A': 3.5608511808228,
  'TCGA.A4.7288.01A': 3.59785191986549,
  'TCGA.A4.7583.01A': 3.61081652486307},
 'ACTR3': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A': 3.57350203736343,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A': 3.50311866574467,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A': 3.55921764196203,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A': 3.52085374326433,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A': 3.49540458365642,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A': 3.46274937035809,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A': 3.61687663274809,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A': 3.53488318379022,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A': 3.58139427546552,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A': 3.6252928636073,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A': 3.54126420446724,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A': 3.42425304944404,
  'TCGA.4A.A93W.01A': 3.55142422147974,
  'TCGA.4A.A93X.01A': 3.53947155870953,
  'TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A': 3.62867013082177,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A': 3.52046634871136,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A': 3.46109723266569,
  'TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A': 3.52279905533904,
  'TCGA.A4.7288.01A': 3.54143423875656,
  'TCGA.A4.7583.01A': 3.55995707578027},
 'ACTR5': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A': 3.06208977903951,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A': 2.98674440955131,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A': 2.86631208756685,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A': 2.8694202685852,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A': 2.88420379057496,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A': 3.0767417839652,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A': 2.94882975283664,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A': 2.78229187971361,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A': 3.02573502430246,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A': 2.77839929937136,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A': 2.92446170648467,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A': 3.04359241380142,
  'TCGA.4A.A93W.01A': 3.09981160346012,
  'TCGA.4A.A93X.01A': 3.04610935341119,
  'TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A': 2.93746503709784,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A': 2.9687386310118,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A': 3.14682227496638,
  'TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A': 2.92895997480749,
  'TCGA.A4.7288.01A': 2.96727191950339,
  'TCGA.A4.7583.01A': 2.88705049070341},
 'ACYP1': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A': 2.68316568819909,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A': 2.98727853617499,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A': 2.8747308602562,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A': 2.90471648931281,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A': 2.86024251917032,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A': 2.90719465672888,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A': 2.58190565590721,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A': 2.83706565172417,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A': 2.71150852376803,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A': 2.71288741077102,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A': 2.91917976563717,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A': 2.92401107924786,
  'TCGA.4A.A93W.01A': 2.94132783915943,
  'TCGA.4A.A93X.01A': 2.74314584851536,
  'TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A': 2.57130863051519,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A': 2.8605082258947,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A': 2.94478769990945,
  'TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A': 2.86417482049571,
  'TCGA.A4.7288.01A': 2.61921928074634,
  'TCGA.A4.7583.01A': 2.71042008838105},
 'ADAM10': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A': 3.42903685557118,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A': 3.46205062573361,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A': 3.51938053547695,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A': 3.14673944797621,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A': 3.36492099305172,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A': 3.39490201042367,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A': 3.46715479737621,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A': 3.44039615808161,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A': 3.36116354963951,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A': 3.5867772356033,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A': 3.35339021556805,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A': 2.97520964839415,
  'TCGA.4A.A93W.01A': 3.38747266012348,
  'TCGA.4A.A93X.01A': 3.2851543302658,
  'TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A': 3.4227242167674,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A': 3.44397415741342,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A': 3.23530165942945,
  'TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A': 3.36142161259566,
  'TCGA.A4.7288.01A': 3.49056254536074,
  'TCGA.A4.7583.01A': 3.47832924902138},
 'ADAM9': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A': 3.53049168632165,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A': 3.51399144540852,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A': 3.32862177250441,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A': 3.45002783224857,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A': 3.39858172551853,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A': 3.40951698282201,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A': 3.53261871918645,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A': 3.56427113271883,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A': 3.5666376894204,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A': 3.67928221333131,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A': 3.52846377629195,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A': 3.32431774552709,
  'TCGA.4A.A93W.01A': 3.38242032101611,
  'TCGA.4A.A93X.01A': 3.55510206417121,
  'TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A': 3.53322064449544,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A': 3.68697187856072,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A': 3.40680584211452,
  'TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A': 3.46389259376506,
  'TCGA.A4.7288.01A': 3.57916689781317,
  'TCGA.A4.7583.01A': 3.59495681256333},
 'ADAMTS13': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A': 2.99717971627462,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A': 2.95643583141984,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A': 3.14476055183309,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A': 2.86800610878318,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A': 3.08493301972618,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A': 3.24445948158587,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A': 2.97799849398308,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A': 2.99163733709338,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A': 2.90391601226256,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A': 2.53461856974451,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A': 2.81575762806495,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A': 3.11018668033958,
  'TCGA.4A.A93W.01A': 3.05917375698737,
  'TCGA.4A.A93X.01A': 2.62388941886632,
  'TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A': 2.40365175187858,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A': 2.89098304121939,
  'TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A': 3.29226405760134,
  'TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A': 2.91802360558372,
  'TCGA.A4.7288.01A': 2.67994876595419,
  'TCGA.A4.7583.01A': 2.96151763370802}})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem under a similar setup. All I needed to do was call the `ravel()` function to get a 1D rep of my output array. In your case, I would suggest `feature_names[sfs_forward.get_support()].ravel()`